# how to insert UISplitView inside one my View Based application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am working on an iPad application and need some help from you guys.

Actually i want to use UISplitView inside one my View Based application.

The flow of my app would be like following:

```
In main view:
When i Enter username and password and click Login, On Successfull login it should open the second screen using present model view controller.
Now on Second Screen there is a Button to goto Mails. When i click on it It should open up the 3rd screen. again pushed using presentModalViewController, which should have a UISplitViewController to show the emails list and when clicking on any email show the detail of that email.
```

Now please can any one guide me how can i use uisplitView controller inside the Viewbased application templet.
at least post any use full links/source code files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, can you please show us the code you have written so far, or let us know where you're having problems, so we can see where to help?

Comment: Duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601863/how-can-i-add-splitview-to-my-viewbased-app-in-ipad-coding

Comment: Mr.ade its not the duplicate Question.
Me too have the same problem.
But in viewbased application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SplitViewController has to be the RootViewController. From Apple Docs:

"A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create. In other words, you must always install the view from aUISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s window. The panes of your split-view interface may then contain navigation controllers, tab bar controllers, or any other type of view controller you need to implement your interface."

So you cannot do what you want without writing your own container views (in iOS5) instead of using Apple' SplitViewController.