# How can i load nib files of two different classes in the splitviecontroller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

- I was stared with Viewbased application.
- In my app i need to use splitview controller.
- for this purpose i dragged a splitviewcontroller in to xib.
- for the two views of splitview controller i was creaed two new
  classes
- **1.DetailsViewController & 2.RootViewController .**

Now i want to load the xib files to the two views of splitview controller.

my code as follows

```
DetailsViewController *details = [[DetailsViewController alloc] init];
    RootViewController *root = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:details, root, nil];

   // self.view = splitViewController.view;
    [self.view addSubview:splitViewController.view];

    [details release];
    [root release];
```

My previous question regarding this problem:
[how can i add splitview to my viewbased app in ipad coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601863/how-can-i-add-splitview-to-my-viewbased-app-in-ipad-coding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
[[MyVC alloc] init]
```

use

```
[[MyVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyNibNameWithoutExtension" bundleOrNil:nil];
```

Comment: ThanQ Kendall it's working. Root vie controller loaded in it's circumstances. but details view not yet loaded, in it's space.

By the way now iam using splitview dinamically. not through the IB

Comment: UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init]; 
    DetailsViewController *details = [[DetailsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
    RootViewController *root = [[RootViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
    splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:details, root, nil];
    [self.view addSubview:splitViewController.view];
    [details release];
    [root release];