# didSelectRowAtIndexpath method for root / tableView in splitviewCotroller

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

- I am using split view controller in my project,
- in the split view i have RootViewCotroller (left),
  DetaolsViewConroller (right).
- In the Root view controller, I have 3 rows.
- Now I want different type of appearance in details view, when
  selecting different rows in rootview.
- ...
- in Details view:
- 1.Display a tableView when select the row1.
- 2.Dispaly a text field when select the row2.
- 3.Image view when select row3 from rootviewcontroller.
- ..
- I wrote the code like this in RootViecontroller, but no change in
  detailsView.
  -

```m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

       {
           RightViewController *rightViewController = [[RightViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RightViewController"bundle:nil];
           //[self.navigationController pushViewController:rightViewController animated:YES];

           if(indexPath.row == 0)
           {
               UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 450, 150)];
               infoLabel.text = @"Customer:Barrick \r\n Mine:gold \r\n Location:USA";
               [rightViewController.view addSubview:infoLabel];

               UITableView *mapTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, 5, 450,150)style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
               [rightViewController.view addSubview:mapTable];
           }

           if(indexPath.row == 1)
           {
               UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 450, 150)];
               infoLabel.text = @"Eqipement";
               [rightViewController.view addSubview:infoLabel];
           }


           if(indexPath.row == 2)
           {
             image view..   
           }

           [rightViewController release];
       }
```

- what to do..? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a value to the right view controller and you have to also set delegate for your right view controller.

Define your right View Controller in your left view controller like:

```
RightViewController *detail;
  /// in implementation of left view contrloller
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
    NSUInteger item = [indexPath row] +1;
    NSNumber *detailItem = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:item];
    self.detailCar.detailItem = detailItem;
}
```

Define in your rightViewController.h file :

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSNumber *detailItem;
```

In Your RightViewController's implementation file:

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(NSNumber *)newDetailItem {
    NSLog(@"ConfigTItem");
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        [_detailItem release]; 
        _detailItem = [newDetailItem retain]; 
        [self configureView];
    }
    else {
        [self configureView]; 
    }
}

- (void)configureView {        
    if (self.detailItem) {
        [self viewDidLoad];  // 
        //set your method's and variable whatever you want to do in your view did load or directly here
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working but with a small issue

i've used code like as follows

Comment: if( detailItem == [NSNumber numberWithInt:1])
     {
         NSLog(@"Configure item at row 1 %@",detailItem);
         UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 450, 150)];
         infoLabel.text = @"Customer:Barrick Gold\r\nMine:Turquiose Ridge Mine \r\nLocation:Mesa, AZ";
         [self.view addSubview:infoLabel];
   
}

Comment: if( detailItem == [NSNumber numberWithInt:2])
    {
         NSLog(@"Config item at row 2 %@",detailItem); 
 UITableView *mapTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, 5, 450,150  style:UITableViewStyleGrouped]; 
         [self.view addSubview:mapTable];  
  
     }
    
    if( self.detailItem == [NSNumber numberWithInt:3]) 
     { 
         NSLog(@"Config item at row 3 %@",detailItem);
     }

Comment: It's working but with a small issue i've used code like as follows

Comment: Here NSLog works in console..... but the sub view like..: label,UITableView are not added in detailsview

whats the problem..

Comment: have you load your methods? when you select any of row first load the configview not a viewDidLoad method

Comment: Yes sir i did like that only.. even though no result in details view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643057/in-split-view-controller-didselect-method-not-working

This link has my entire code, leftViewController .h, .m .. 
Right view controlle .h, .m

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643057/in-split-view-controller-didselect-method-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to render view from another controller. On click of the row pass the index value of row to the rightView controller. Then render the view depending upon the value of row in rightView controller.

Comment: Thanks for quick responce.
then what to do now to pass the indexvalue to the righview controller?

Comment: Create a property for row say indexRowVal of integer type in right view controller and assign the value to it in root controller as rightViewController.indexRowVal = [indexPath row].

Comment: Even you can create a method to initialize and call it from rootView controller.