# in Split view controller didSelect method not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

i am working on splitviewcontroller in window based application
im writing code as follows but didselect not working

in LeftViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class RightViewController;
@interface LeftViewController : UITableViewController
{
    RightViewController *details;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSNumber *detailItem;

@end
```

**InLeftviewController.m: didselectmethod:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RightViewController *rightViewController = [[RightViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RightViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rightViewController animated:YES];

    NSUInteger item = [indexPath row];
    rightViewController.detailItem = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:item];
    rightViewController.detailItem = detailItem;
    NSLog(@"detailItem= %@ , %@", detailItem,rightViewController.detailItem );

    int i = [detailItem intValue];
    if(detailItem == [NSNumber numberWithInt:0])
    {
        //Adding label to the details view
        UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 450, 150)];
        infoLabel.text = @"Customer:Barrick Gold\r\nMine:Turquiose Ridge Mine \r\nLocation:Mesa, AZ";
        [rightViewController.view addSubview:infoLabel];

        //Adding table view to the details view
        UITableView *mapTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, 5, 450,150) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        [rightViewController.view addSubview:mapTable];
    }

    if(item == 1)
    {
        UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 450, 150)];
        infoLabel.text = @"Eqipement";
        [rightViewController.view addSubview:infoLabel];
    }

    if(i == 2)
    {

    }
}
```

in RightViewController.h:

```
@interface RightViewController : UIViewController
{
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSNumber *detailItem;
```

**in RightViewController.m :**

```
#import "RightViewController.h"
#import "LeftViewController.h"

@implementation RightViewController
@synthesize detailItem;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)configureView
{
    if (self.detailItem) 
    {
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    //set a background color Just to recognize the layout of the View
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    // To display Tiltle & EditButton on the navigation bar for this view controller.
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    self.title= @"Customer Name";
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)setDetailItem:(NSNumber *)newDetailItem
{
    //LeftViewController *left = [[LeftViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LeftViewController" bundle:nil];
    int i = [detailItem intValue];
    NSLog(@"Config item %d",i);

     if( detailItem == [NSNumber numberWithInt:0])
     {
         NSLog(@"Configure item at row 1 %@",detailItem);

         //Adding label to the view
         UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 450, 150)];
         infoLabel.text = @"Customer:Barrick Gold\r\nMine:Turquiose Ridge Mine \r\nLocation:Mesa, AZ";
         [self.view addSubview:infoLabel];

         //Adding table view to the view.
         UITableView *mapTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, 5, 450,150) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
         [self.view addSubview:mapTable];
    }

    if( detailItem == [NSNumber numberWithInt:1])
    {
         NSLog(@"Config item at row 2 %@",detailItem);
    }

    if( self.detailItem == [NSNumber numberWithInt:2])
    {
        NSLog(@"Config item at row 3 %@",detailItem);
    }

    if (detailItem != newDetailItem)
    {
        [detailItem release]; 
        detailItem = [newDetailItem retain]; 
        [self configureView];
    }

    else
    {
        [self configureView]; 
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Why are You using Split view. Instead of splitview You can fallow example which is Your friend suggest with UItableview and another view concept.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying here. If the `LeftViewController` and `RightViewController` are the master and detail views of the split view then why are you trying to push the detail view from the master view. The function of the split view is to show the details of the selected item in the master view(left view) on the detail view on the right side(detail view). So why would you bother pushing that view in the master view. All you have to do is to set the detail item for the `DetailViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the line at the end of didSelect method of tableview in leftView controller`[self.navigationController pushViewController:rightViewController animated:YES];`

Comment: I was tried pusViewController, PresentModel View controller.. Even though No result sir